# " is it ok to subtract the var size in the function(isFull()) or is it better to do that in the constructor?"

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

```
 //Constructor
    Cons(size){
    maxsize=size-1;
    }
```

```
    //isFull Function
    public boolean isFull(){
            return top==maxsize-1;
        }
```

But if we try to subtract the maxsize into a function it will change every time when we run this function ,so do we just have to do that in the constructor then we can prevent the maxsize from getting decreased every time when we run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maxsize - 1 does not decrease maxsize, it just calculates the value. If you’re worried about the cost of the calculation, then you shouldn’t be :)

Anyway, if the size is fixed then you should do it in the constructor to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

```
//Constructor
Cons(size){
maxsize=size-1; //maxsize value updated
}
```

> constructor is decreasing maxsize by 1

```
//isFull Function
public boolean isFull(){
        return top==maxsize-1; //returns true or false and without changing any value
    }
```

> while isFull is only returning the boolean value and not actually subtracting 1 from maxsize

you can prevent maxsize from decreasing by doing what isFull is doing right now and not doing as below

```
//isFull Function
public boolean isFull(){
        return top==maxsize--; //returns true or false and decreases maxsize by 1        }
```